# how to have two different users to handle EF core migration and CRUD

Tags: docker, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I am looking for a solution to handle two different SQL users, the Superuser to do EF core migration and a low privilege user to handle application CRUD. However, the solution is to dockerize the application and the SQL users should be able to pass as env variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to override OnConfiguring method in DbContext, and there you can set different connection string (different user) based on some condition.

.AddDbContext extension method register DbContext as scoped service, so you should be able to handle purpose of every instantiation of DbContext.

I'll try to give you idea of it:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    public ApplicationDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
    {
        bool someCondition = true;
        builder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString(someCondition ? "SuperUserConnectionString" : "CrudConnectionString"));
    }
}
```